# Submit webform via POST on restful API with angularjs: Input textbox gives TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

I am trying to submit a webform on my Drupal 7 site through my Angular code. What I am doing is to have Drupal 7 as a backend and an App (through ionic + Angular) as a frontend.

What is happening that when I try to submit form and for some reason whenever I try to type in my textbox, it gives me:-

```
TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
    at extend.assign (angular.js:10626)
    at $setViewValue (angular.js:17502)
    at angular.js:16818
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:12518)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:12616)
    at HTMLInputElement.listener (angular.js:16817)
    at HTMLInputElement.x.event.dispatch (jquery-1.10.min.js:5)
    at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery-1.10.min.js:5)
```

Here is the complete code how I am sending data to Drupal 7 site to submit the webform.

### The textbox is here with the complete form:-

```
<form ng-submit="submit('1234wewewdsd')" ng-controller="formCtrl" method="POST">
          <label>Your name:</label><br/>
          <input type="text" ng-model="formData[1]['values'][0]" value="Fahad" /><br/>
           <label>Your detail:</label><br/>
          <input type="text" ng-model="formData[2]['values'][0]" value="DEtails" /><br/>
          <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>
```

### My Angular Code is below:-

`app.js`

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
])
```

`services.js`

```
    .factory('formService', function($http){
    return {
        postForm: function(uuid, $scope){
          var toPost = {
            webform: uuid,
            submission: {
                data: $scope.formData
            }
          };
          console.log(toPost);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(toPost));
          return $http.post('http://localhost:8888/mysite/api/submission', toPost);
        }
    };
})
```

`controller.js`

```
.controller('formCtrl', function($scope, $element, formService) {
    $scope.submit = function(uuid){
      formService.postForm(uuid, this);
    };
})
```

### Correct URL parameters needed to sent with response

[image]

Comment: What is `formData`? Show us its structure if you could.

Comment: Please add the code where you define `$scope.formData`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for looking into it. I took help from the code mentioned here and there is no mention of `formData`. I'll be grateful if you could look at this link -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889528/drupal-how-to-submit-the-webfrom-from-rest-services-using-ajax-post

Comment: Is this really related Ionic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `$scope.formData` in your controller, like this:

```
$scope.formData = {1: {values: {}}, 2: {values: {}}, 5: {values: {}} };
```

Then, in your form, change your `ng-model` like this:

```
<form ng-submit="submit('8107a8e2-525a-4e57-a8cd-e4ec50e7979d')" ng-controller="formCtrl" method="POST">
      <label>Your name:</label><br/>
      <input type="text" ng-model="formData[1]['values'][0]" /><br/>
       <label>Your detail:</label><br/>
      <input type="text" ng-model="formData[2]['values'][0]"  /><br/>

      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you Thieu, this indeed helped and fixed the error but it gives the output of `{"webform":"8107a8e2-525a-4e57-a8cd-e4ec50e7979d","submission":{"data":{"name":"Faisal","detail":"Details"}}}`. I was hoping to get the output of in the format of `submission[data][1][values][0]` . I therefore kept the `ng-model="formData[1]['values'][0]"` in my question.

Comment: I also pasted a postman screenshot in my question, where I am sending correct parameters.

Comment: If you want to keep original ng-model, maybe you can set `$scope.formData = {1: {values: {}}, 2: {values: {}}};`, please check it again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Plnk link with working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/NxE2SdK4qIcsSAjCPrIO?p=preview) of your code.

so you need to declare your Array in specific format. I have updated example accordingly. have a look.

```
<form ng-submit="submit('810riw42-525a-4e57-a8cd-e4ec50e7979d')" ng-controller="formCtrl" method="POST">
      <label>Your name:</label><br/>
      <input type="text" ng-model="formData[0]['values'][0]" /><br/>
       <label>Your detail:</label><br/>
      <input type="text" ng-model="formData[1]['values'][0]" /><br/>
      <input type="button" value="Send" ng-click="submit('810riw42-525a-4e57-a8cd-e4ec50e7979d')" />
    </form>




 // Create the controller, the 'ToddlerCtrl' parameter 
// must match an ng-controller directive
myApp.controller('formCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.formData = [ 
        {
          'values': ['Your Name']
        },
        {
          'values': ['Your detail']
        }
    ];

   $scope.submit = function(uuid){
     console.log($scope.formData[0]['values'][0])
     return false;
    };

});
```

Comment: Thanks Abid, but I was hoping to have the submission array as `submission[data][1][values][0]`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: well, then you need to declare it like , $scope.formData = [ 
        {
          'values': [1,2,3]
        }
    ];

Comment: Thanks Abid, It now comes like `{"webform":"8107a8e2-525a-4e57-a8cd-e4ec50e7979d","submission":{"data":[{"values":[1,2,3]}]}}`. I am using `<input type="text" ng-model="formData.name" />` and `<input type="text" ng-model="formData.detail" />`. When I use `<input type="text" ng-model="formData[0]['values'][0]" />`, it gives me the same error as mentioned in the question